# Web Content Partial matching algorithm suggestions?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, algorithms, matching, internet

I am trying to find a word or set of words or a similar word in the new web page scraped from publicly available sources to answer a question. I have a small list of keywords against which I would like to match the data fetched from new web page to classify the new web page as yes or no. I am unable to build a classifier due to less data points(<50) and tried Fuzzy match algorithms but they are producing a lot of false positives. Are they any Statistical/ML algorithms to rightly classify the new web page?